# Align embedded Media Images

Tags: 8, media

When I embed an image into CKEditor text I can choose alignment options. When I embed a Media Image I cannot choose alignment, but a Media View. A media View allows me to specify image size (via image style) but not alignment

Embedding an Image does not add the image to the Media Library and it would be nice to *only* use Media Image embedding so as to manage the site's media library of images.

What is the preferred way of specifying the alignment of embedded Media?

**Background**

I am switching over to simply using core Media modules in Drupal 8.8. I have ditched what I was previously using:
*  Embed
*  Entity Embed
*  DropzoneJS entity browser widget
*  Entity Browser
*  Entity Browser IEF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest to resolve (and most likely) issue is:

You are limiting the allowed HTML tags for the text format you're using and you haven't allowed the align (and also caption, if you want captions) attributes for the `drupal-entity` HTML element. (I'm assuming you do have the `Align images` and `Caption images` filters enabled because you said those features were working for non-media embeds. If they're not enabled, enable them.)

**Solution:**

In the "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" section (`/admin/config/content/formats/manage/MY_FORMAT#edit-filters-filter-html-settings`), make sure the `drupal-entity` has at least the `data-align` (and `data-caption` for captions) attributes. E.g. `<drupal-entity data-align data-caption data-etc...>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply. I am pretty sure you correctly identified the solution to my issue. I’ll verify that this is the correct answer tomorrow on my dev site. Thanks to your pointer I found the documentation page that I’d not found before (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/media-library-module/embedding-media-with-ckeditor)

Comment: I then edited the Drupal docs to include the  data-view-mode attribute thus: "Additionally, if you have the "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" filter enabled, you must ensure that the drupal-media tag also allows the alt, data-align, data-caption, and data-view-mode attributes in order for Alternate text, Align, Caption and Display options, respectively, to be effective in the "Edit media" dialog."

Comment: Thank you for editing the docs! I moved your paragraph to the middle of the doc where other edits to filter settings are discussed because I missed it initially.

This actually wasn't enough to fix this for me however. Left and right alignment worked, but center did not. Center worked within CKEditor, but not when the page was rendered. In order to get images centered aligned, within the CSS of my theme I had to add `.align-center { text-align: center; }`. I can't explain why this is the case and since this seems to work for everyone else I won't open a bug report.